# Lg Optimums L3 (e400f) Continuously Syncing Problem

Tags: lg, stock-rom, active-sync, lg-optimus-l3

My Lg Optimums L3 (e400) Is Always continuously syncing, from when I boot up till I shutdown, even when the setting is turned off. I think this started happening after I used the inbuilt power widget to turn automatic syncing off and since then I have been unable to get the icon to disappear. How can I Fix this problem?

[image: Image 1] [image: Image 2]

Comment: What does your task manager say the battery consumption is for sync?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be showing, I would geuss that it isn't acually syncing but rather the icon isn't going away. But i can't be sure as battery use is only showing me this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/HWdWW.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a factory reset, I had found out that Google play services was the culprit, the reason that the icon stayed up there was because I had stopped the application once while it was syncing, and since then the icon stayed up.

*I still don't know the reason why it did that.*